# A same suid + system program, different outputs on different systems

Tags: c, linux, suid

I write a simple program named `suid.c`:

```c
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
        system(argv[1]);
}
```

Compile it with gcc then set suid permission (root user now):

```
# gcc suid.c -o suid
# chmod +s suid
```

I tried to run `./suid id` with the www-data user on different virtual machines, but the output is different.

- The output in kali 2019: `id=33(www-data) gid=33(www-data) groups=33(www-data)`
- The output in ubuntu trusty(a old linux): `uid=33(www-data) gid=33(www-data) euid=0(root) egid=0(root) groups=0(root),33(www-data)`

Why is that? Has anything changed in Linux?

Comment: This might be related to differences in dropping SUID privileges of different shells.

Comment: What does `man id` say on Kali? Does it say it outputs the effective user and group ids? What does just running `id` say?

Comment: @Rob Sorry for it, I'll update it soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends whether `/bin/sh` is bash or dash on your distribution. Bash [always drops setuid/setgid privileges unless invoked with the option `-p`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/shell.c?h=bash-4.4#n503). Dash doesn't do anything special about privileges.

On Ubuntu, the `system` function invokes `sh`, which is `/bin/sh`, which is dash, which doesn't drop privileges. On Kali, the `system` function invokes `sh`, which is `/bin/sh`, which is bash, which drops privileges. It's a matter of which shell the distribution installs as `sh`, not of how recent the distribution is.

Bash's behavior can be a security countermeasure, but it isn't a very effective one. It's a second line of defense against misguided configurations or badly written programs that run with privileges that they shouldn't have, and allow untrusted input to functions such as `system`. However, such programs usually have other holes that allow the potential attacker to attack anyway, such as the ability to write to files.

Answer (score 4):

As noted in a comment above, you're seeing the effects of `system()` dropping setuid on purpose (indirectly via bash).

My Amazon Linux instance notes for `system(3)`:

> Do not use system() from a program with set-user-ID or set-group-ID privileges, because strange values for some environment  variables  might
>   be  used  to  subvert  system integrity.  Use the exec(3) family of functions instead, but not execlp(3) or execvp(3).  system() will not, in
>   fact, work properly from programs with set-user-ID or set-group-ID privileges on systems on which /bin/sh is bash version  2,  since  bash  2
>   drops privileges on startup.  (Debian uses a modified bash which does not do this when invoked as sh.)

Running `system()` from a setuid program is **super dangerous** because it's way, way easier to subvert your intentions than you think (hijacking `$IFS` would be a good place to start).

Using one of the `exec` functions at least gets the shell out of the way, but there's often another shell down the road.

If you absolutely have to do this, you can call `setuid(geteuid());` prior to `system()`, which essentially throws away the fact that you're in a setuid environment - where real and effective users are different - by saying that *both* are the elevated user. Likewise with group. This is probably a terrible idea.

I might suggest that if you have to ask SO how to do setuid, you may not be in the best position to do it safely.